# Is there a better way to "hide" a div? (currently using insertAdjacentHTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, insert, hide

So here is the javascript I am currently using:

```
var submitcount = 0;
    function arrow(definition) {
        if (submitcount == 0 || submitcount % 2 == 0) {
            var extension = document.getElementById('one');
            extension.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="before-two"><div id="two"><div class="btn-group"><!----><button type="button" class="left" onclick="modify_qtyTag(1,"seven")"></button><!----><button type="button" class="tag" id="seven" data-votes="0" data-upvotes="0">seven</button><!----><button type="button" class="right" onclick="modify_qtyTag(0,"seven")"></button><!----></div><div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="left" onclick="modify_qtyTag(1,"eight")"></button><!----><button type="button" class="tag" id="eight" data-votes="0" data-upvotes="0">eight</button><!----><button type="button" class="right" onclick="modify_qtyTag(0,"eight")"></button></div><p><div class="btn-group"><!----><button type="button" class="left" onclick="modify_qtyTag(1,"antonyms")"></button><!----><button type="button" class="tag" id="antonyms" data-votes="0" data-upvotes="0">antonyms</button><!----><button type="button" class="right" onclick="modify_qtyTag(0,"antonyms")"></button><!----></div><div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="left" onclick="modify_qtyTag(1,"gentle")"></button><!----><button type="button" class="tag" id="gentle" data-votes="0" data-upvotes="0">gentle</button><!----><button type="button" class="right" onclick="modify_qtyTag(0,"gentle")"></button></div></p></div></div></div>');
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('two')) {
            var deleted = document.getElementById('before-two');
            deleted.remove(deleted.selectedIndex);  
        }
        submitcount += 1;
    };
```

The insertAdjacentHTML is enormous and will only get bigger... There has to be a better way to do this, be it through Javascript or just HTML/CSS. Please help!

PS: If you need/want the full JSFiddle, just let me know.

Thanks so much!

Comment: a JSFiddle will definitely provide some more context.

Comment: Also, know that [`[elem].style.display = "none"`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) hides an element.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Also, `element.hidden` if you want to hide it from all devices (including non-visual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively include that HTML that you've got inside the insertAdjacentHTML in the actual page markup, and then hide it using CSS display property:

```
div#before-two {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, use your javascript to select `#before-two` and append it to `#one` and change the CSS to `display: block`.